# Unexpected clash between babel and pgf spy

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, babel, option-clash, spy

The following example taken from the pgfplots manual (p. 121) works
fine only if the line loading `babel` is commented

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} % this is the troubelsome line

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines=
{circle, magnification=6, connect spies}]
\begin{axis}[no markers,grid=major,
every axis plot post/.append style={thick}]
\addplot coordinates
{(0, 0.0) (0, 0.9) (1, 0.9) (2, 1) (3, 0.9) (80,
 0)};
\addplot +[line join=round] coordinates
{(0, 0.0) (0, 0.9) (2, 0.9) (3, 1) (4, 0.9) (80,
 0)};
\addplot +[line join=bevel] coordinates
{(0, 0.0) (0, 0.9) (3, 0.9) (4, 1) (5, 0.9) (80,
 0)};
\addplot +[miter limit=5] coordinates
{(0, 0.0) (0, 0.9) (4, 0.9) (5, 1) (6, 0.9) (80,
 0)};
\coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:3,1);
\coordinate (magnifyglass) at (axis cs:60,0.7);
\end{axis}
\spy [blue, size=2.5cm] on (spypoint)
in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error

```
Runaway argument?
[fill=white] at (magnifyglass); 
! Paragraph ended before \tikz@lib@spy@parse@opta was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

which I fail to interpret.

I'm using the `TeX Live` distribution that ships with Ubuntu but I
manually installed in my *texmf* folder more recent version of some
packages including `pgf` and `pgfplots`.

Do you have any idea of what I could do to be able to use both `babel`
and the `spy` library?

Comment: If you are using TikZ 3.0, just add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` to your preamble. See: [tikz declare function and babel french option](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187574/1952)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `french` language sets the `;` as an active character: use `\shorthandoff{;}` before the picture and `\shorthandon{;}` after the picture to not have problems.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{;}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines=
{circle, magnification=6, connect spies}]
\begin{axis}[no markers,grid=major,
every axis plot post/.append style={thick}]
\addplot coordinates
{(0, 0.0) (0, 0.9) (1, 0.9) (2, 1) (3, 0.9) (80,
 0)};
\addplot +[line join=round] coordinates
{(0, 0.0) (0, 0.9) (2, 0.9) (3, 1) (4, 0.9) (80,
 0)};
\addplot +[line join=bevel] coordinates
{(0, 0.0) (0, 0.9) (3, 0.9) (4, 1) (5, 0.9) (80,
 0)};
\addplot +[miter limit=5] coordinates
{(0, 0.0) (0, 0.9) (4, 0.9) (5, 1) (6, 0.9) (80,
 0)};
\coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:3,1);
\coordinate (magnifyglass) at (axis cs:60,0.7);
\end{axis}
\spy [blue, size=2.5cm] on (spypoint)
in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass);
\end{tikzpicture}
\shorthandon{;}
\end{document}
```

Notice that the previous MWE raise the following warnings

```
Package frenchb.ldf Warning: OT1 encoding should not be used for French.
```

that can be avoided by means of:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % before babel
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
```

and:

```
Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode unsuitable tick labels; missing features).
```

solvable through:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6} % change this according to the current version of pgfplots
```

Answer (score 9):

TikZ is usually intelligent with regard to active characters and so does not normally need the `\shorthandon`, `\shorthandoff` pair.  However, the `spy` library did not include the checks that TikZ uses when matching its command and only defines a variant for whatever catcode semi-colon has at load-time.  Since babel shifts its catcode changes to `\begin{document}`, this means that the `\spy` command tests against the wrong catcode.  One fix is, as Claudio says, to return the semi-colon to its original state.  Another fix is to augment the spy library by TikZ's intelligent semi-colon handling.  The following code does this second method.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74860/86}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} % this is the troubelsome line

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@spy@parse@opt[#1]{%
    \let\tikz@spy@next=\tikz@lib@spy@parse@opta%
    \ifnum\the\catcode`\;=\active\relax
     \let\tikz@spy@next=\tikz@lib@spy@parse@opta@activesemicolon
    \fi
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar x{\tikz@spy@next[#1]}{\tikz@spy@next[#1]}%]
}
{
\catcode`\;=\active
\gdef\tikz@lib@spy@parse@opta@activesemicolon[#1]on#2in node#3;{%
  \pgfutil@g@addto@macro\tikz@lib@spy@collection{\tikz@lib@spy@do{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines=
{circle, magnification=6, connect spies}]
\begin{axis}[no markers,grid=major,
every axis plot post/.append style={thick}]
\addplot coordinates
{(0, 0.0) (0, 0.9) (1, 0.9) (2, 1) (3, 0.9) (80,
 0)};
\addplot +[line join=round] coordinates
{(0, 0.0) (0, 0.9) (2, 0.9) (3, 1) (4, 0.9) (80,
 0)};
\addplot +[line join=bevel] coordinates
{(0, 0.0) (0, 0.9) (3, 0.9) (4, 1) (5, 0.9) (80,
 0)};
\addplot +[miter limit=5] coordinates
{(0, 0.0) (0, 0.9) (4, 0.9) (5, 1) (6, 0.9) (80,
 0)};
\coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:3,1);
\coordinate (magnifyglass) at (axis cs:60,0.7);
\end{axis}
\spy [blue, size=2.5cm] on (spypoint)
in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: spying on babel]

(Though I guess the *real* result is that it compiles.)