# Tikzmark and french seem to conflict

Tags: french, tikzmark

I just discovered `tikzmark` thanks to the [blog](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2013/04/beware-the-tikzmark-my-son/?cb=1), and it sounds really promising. I downloaded the files from CTAN and put `tikzlibrarytikzmark.code.tex` and `tikzmarklibrarylistings.code.tex` in the same folder as my main `.tex` file. I'm trying to reproduce the first example from the manual itself, *en français*.

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}

   \[
     \tikzmark{a} \frac{x^2}{n!}
   \]

  Test \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=0pt] \draw[->] (0,1em) to (pic cs:a);

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I guess it has to do with the `:` colon in the `tikzmark` specific syntax, right? Any ideas on what to do? This compiles just fine if I replace `french` with `english`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not the colon, it's a buried non-active semi-colon.

TikZ is super-clever with regard to active semi-colons.  When it starts a `\tikz` command (or a `\draw` or whatever) then it calls a certain macro to gather in the rest of the command.  The rest of the command is everything up to the next semi-colon ("up to" with the usual proviso of TeX groupings).  However, as there are popular packages like `babel` make the semi-colon active then the semi-colon delimiting the TikZ command could be either active or non-active (well, it could be a host of things but those are the most likely) and the two are not equivalent.  So TikZ checks the state of the semi-colon before calling the macro and calls a different one depending on the state of the semi-colon.

All very well and good.

Enter the `tikzmark`.  This expands to `\tikz <something>;`.  However, it is defined before the document officially begins.  This means that the semi-colon has the status of the preambelic semi-colon.  `babel` only changes the state of the semi-colon at the start of the actual document meaning that *this* semi-colon is not active.  But when the `\tikzmark` is actually used, TikZ checks the *current* semi-colon status.  So it starts looking for an active semi-colon but doesn't find it, causing it to bail out in confusion.

There are probably a few solutions, but I suspect that the best is for `\tikzmark` to do its own semi-colonic check and use the Right Semi-Colon^TM (TM = tikzmark).

Here's some code that will do that:

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110014/86}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\makeatletter

\begingroup
\catcode`\;=\active

\gdef\tikzmark@active#1#2{%
\tikz[remember picture with id=#2] #1;}

\endgroup
\def\tikzmark@nonactive#1#2{%
\tikz[remember picture with id=#2] #1;}

\renewcommand\tikzmark[2][]{%
\ifnum\catcode`\;=\active
\let\@next=\tikzmark@active
\else
\let\@next=\tikzmark@nonactive
\fi
\@next{#1}{#2}}


\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}

   \[
     \tikzmark{a}
 \frac{x^2}{n!}
   \]

  Test \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=0pt] \draw[->] (0,1em) to (pic cs:a);

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Assuming that no-one tells me that this the Wrong Implementation of Catcode Protection^TM then I'll stick this in the tikzmark code an upload it to CTAN.

*Added for clarity* This is *in essence* the same as the problem encountered in [tikz declare function and babel french option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86023) and [Unexpected clash between babel and pgf spy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74860).  For each of these then I prefer the solution that involves modifying the original code to cope with active semi-colons - which is what I've done above.  Figuring out exactly what needs modifying in such cases is a bit different in each case.  Those other questions contain other possibilities that don't require this modification and so are easier for someone to implement themselves in a similar situation.  *However*, I would warn that using `beamer` can cause a few hiccoughs where catcodes are concerned since catcodes are "frozen" inside frames unless you use the `fragile` option.

Comment: No need to scan the arguments twice, just do \renewcommand\tikzmark{%
\ifnum\catcode'\;=\active
\expandafter\tikzmark@active
\else
\expandafter\tikzmark@nonactive
\fi
}  (after putting the `'` back to a backtick)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then I'd need to define `\tikzmark@active` and `\tikzmark@nonactive` via `\newcommand` so that they could deal with the optional argument, no?

Comment: @percusse That would be okay, except it could lead to unexpected behaviour if you put something into the `\tikzmark` arguments that used a semi-colon since it wouldn't behave the same way as outside.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I don't think that's the case if you prefix the code..

Comment: @AndrewStacey oh I guess so.

Comment: Brilliant. Let me know when the CTAN download is updated please.

Comment: @percusse I'd need to see an example.

Comment: @ChristophB. I've uploaded it to the TeX-SX Launchpad page (http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files).

Comment: Could you take a look at my modification of `\tikzmark` in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335569/)? My suggestion is almost certainly not quite right and certainly not as elegant as you'd come up with, but it does solve the problem raised in the question I'm responding to, which is that the code above breaks in the case that both the `babel` package and the `babel` Ti*k*Z library are loaded. Since this is a standard recommendation when using Ti*k*Z with language configurations which make various characters active, it would be good if `tikzmark` could handle this case, too.