# Clash between tikzmark, babel package (french) and babel tikzlibrary

Tags: babel, tikzmark, tikzlibrary

Related : [Tikzmark and french seem to conflict](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110014/tikzmark-and-french-seem-to-conflict)

I post this question with a workaround in comment for three reasons :

- may be this can be useful to another user.
- the workaround is successful only if babel package and babel tikzlibrary are loaded together.
- somebody can surely provide a better answer than my workaround.

I don't see another question here like that but if i missed one, let me know and i delete mine.

With this MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,babel,tikzmark}
\begin{document}
test\tikzmark{a} 

Go to test\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw[->] to (pic cs:a);.
\end{document}
```

The document doesn't compile.

It compile if we remove babel in \usetikzlibrary or babel package.

Question : how can we make \tikzmark do its job with babel package AND babel library as well as with babel package and without babel library.

Comment: Put  "\makeatletter \let\tikzmark@active\tikzmark@nonactive \makeatother" after \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark} and the document compile fine. The correction added by @loopspace fail if we call babel in \usetikzlibrary and french option in Babel package.

Comment: But your work around will fail if you don't use babel library.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. Sure, my workaround is needed only if we use babel package AND babel library. If not, the tikzmark package does its job perfectly. I've edited my question to be more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new version of `tikzmark` is available for testing from [github](https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark) which hopefully gets rid of all the active/non-active/deactive/reactive semi-colon issues.

Turns out that there's an alternative form of the underlying `\tikz` command which avoids semi-colons.  Instead of `\tikz[...] ...;` one can write `\tikz[...]{...}` and `\tikzmark` now uses this form.

Please test it by downloading `tikzmark.dtx`, running `tex tikzmark.dtx`, and putting the generated files somewhere that `tex` can find them.  Then try it out with your documents and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'll give it a try as soon as possible but it was my first use of tikzmark so i've not a lot of tests to do actually. I'll see for more tests when i'll find some time. I'll mail you my results to the adress wrote in the tikzmark doc.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the `tikzmark` tests whether or not the semicolon is active and proceeds accordingly. Now, the `babel` package makes the semicolon active when `frenchb` is active. `tikzmark` copes fine with that because the test is true and it proceeds on that basis. However, the `babel` Ti*k*Z library tries to handle active characters in code in Ti*k*Z pictures, too, so its attempts to avoid the issues caused by the `babel` package making the semicolon active conflict with the attempts of `tikzmark` to avoid the same issues. Essentially two things trying to avoid the problems end up counteracting each other.

Note that I do not understand this well enough to give a blow-by-blow account and even the above gesturing at one might be mistaken, but something like this seems to be going on.

The real issue here, I think, is that `tikzmark` should not assume that if the semicolon is active when `\tikzmark` is used, it will also be active inside `tikzpicture`s because this will not typically be true if the `babel` Ti*k*Z library is used. Since this is a standard recommendation when documents use Babel configurations which make characters active, `tikzmark` essentially breaks code written in accordance with best practice.

I think `tikzmark` should test to see which active characters are being handled for code inside `tikzpicture`s. This approach will not guarantee no breakage, but it should prevent breakage in standard cases where uses simply load the `babel` Ti*k*Z library and rely on it to set things up correctly.

You can workaround the problem by redefining `\tikzmark`. For example,

```
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\tikzmark@outside[2][]{%
      \ifnum\catcode`\;=\active
        \iftikz@handle@active@code
          \let\tikzmark@next=\tikzmark@nonactive
        \else
          \let\tikzmark@next=\tikzmark@active
        \fi
      \else
        \let\tikzmark@next=\tikzmark@nonactive
      \fi
      \tikzmark@next{#1}{#2}%
    }    
    \makeatother
```

appears to solve the problem in the MWE, at least, and I hope should workaround it in real documents as well. You *might* also need to test whether Ti*k*Z is handling active characters in nodes. However, this should not matter in the standard case and would need, I think, to be customised for specific cases. In the standard case, where the `babel` library is used, active characters are handled in both code and nodes, so testing one is sufficient. Moreover, in the MWE, at least, handling active characters in nodes but not code did ***not*** reproduce the error, which is why I've tested specifically for the handling in code which causes the problem.

I would, however, recommend reporting this issue to `tikzmark`'s author as there is almost certainly a much more elegant way to handle this issue than the one I've come up with here.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[frenchb]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,tikzmark}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tikzmark@outside[2][]{%
  \ifnum\catcode`\;=\active
    \iftikz@handle@active@code
      \let\tikzmark@next=\tikzmark@nonactive
    \else
      \let\tikzmark@next=\tikzmark@active
    \fi
  \else
    \let\tikzmark@next=\tikzmark@nonactive
  \fi
  \tikzmark@next{#1}{#2}%
}    
\makeatother
\begin{document}
test\tikzmark{a}

Go to test%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \draw[->] (0,0) to ({pic cs:a});
\end{tikzpicture}%
.

\end{document}
```

[image: testing test to test]

Comment: Consider it reported.  My initial reaction is "bleugh, I'm fed up of the active/non-active dilemma". But I'll take a look and see what I can do.

Comment: Oups ... i take the lat 30 min to wrote you an email of 10 words (but english words) so i don't saw your comment..

Comment: @LoopSpace You could just get rid of the test and tell people to use the `babel` Ti*k*Z library. After all, that's what people have to do to make all kinds of other things work. At least that way people could use `tikzmark` and the stuff which requires `babel` without having to fiddle with the lower level stuff, and it would no longer be your problem :-).

Comment: @sbm Sorry, I think that's my fault. I didn't realise the answer you'd linked to was by the package author when I suggested reporting it and then I kind of got distracted.

Comment: @cfr I'd appreciate you testing the latest version, available on github at https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark

Comment: @cfr I've accepted the answer by LoopSpace so i've upvote your answer which is useful too.

Comment: @LoopSpace Thanks. I will take a look and let you know. (I don't know how useful this will be, but I'll try it out.)

Comment: @cfr Fresh eyes are always useful.  If you throw it at a few documents and it still works, that's useful information.

Comment: @LoopSpace Oh, right. I can certainly do that. I use it in some of my teaching stuff. I'll download it and drop it in to replace the current version and give it a whirl.

Comment: @cfr Thanks.  The worst thing would be to think I've squished one bug only to have broken it with existing working documents.

Comment: @LoopSpace It seems to work OK for me with both a parasitic class based on `book` and a parasitic class based on `beamer`. That is, I've not found any problems so far with existing working documents, so it is not only the minimal examples which pass the test. Of course, it might be that my code is systematically odd in some way which just happens to make it work, but I'm not usually that lucky! I'm not using a language with shorthands, though, as all my 'real' documents are English and/or Welsh.

Comment: @LoopSpace Do you plan to push to CTAN? I still seem to need my local copy to override.