# xelatex + frenchb introduce extra spaces before some characters in lstlisting blocks

Tags: spacing, listings, babel, french

When using babel 'frenchb' with xelatex, spaces are introduced before colons and other characters. This is great for prose, but this is also being applied to code snippets. This yields an unacceptable result when rendering code as a monospaced font.

The image below is supposed to read "a:b:c" but the colons are hidden under other letters because of the extra spacing:

[image]

It was generated with this code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} 

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, columns=fixed}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
a:b:c
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure how I should remedy this. I've already tried using other fonts to no avail, and setting `columns=flexible` has the effect of wrecking the vertical alignment because of the extra spaces.

Comment: What are you compiling with? Removing `fontspec` and compiling with `pdflatex`, it works fine.

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using xelatex. Standard latex gave me headaches when dealing with unicode.

Comment: With `xelatex`, the problem appears even without `fontspec`. So you can remove it from your MWE, and mention that you are using `xelatex` instead.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

The fix was to add `\NoAutoSpacing` to the `basicstyle` property of `lstset`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} 

\lstset{ basicstyle=\ttfamily\NoAutoSpacing, columns=fixed }

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
a:b:c
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

`\NoAutoSpacing` is documented [here](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/language/babel/contrib/frenchb/frenchb.pdf). It is a feature found in `frenchb.dtx`, which defines all the language definition macros for the French language.

What remains a mystery to me is why this is needed with xelatex but not with straight latex.

Comment: Note that this way, you might need to add this command to any style you use in your listings.

Comment: The newest version of frenchb uses with xelatex `\XeTeXinterchartoks` to add spaces before a colon. It doesn't make the colon active in xelatex as would be done in latex. And so listings can't make it inactive.

Comment: I really prefer this solution. Way cleaner, as this does not require to play with esoteric etoolbox stuffs proposed in the other answer.
And AFAIK if we use `XeTeXinterchartoks` we might have all spaces before colons removed even outside the listings environment. But on my side, replacing `\NoAutoSpacing` by `\XeTeXinterchartoks` does not work :-/

Answer (score 6):

Add the relevant code in front of `\lstlisting`, which is executed in a group when `\begin{lstlisting}` is encountered.

```
\documentclass{report}

%Uncomment the following to try Polyglossia (and comment the babel line)
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{french}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, columns=fixed}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{XeTeXinterchartokenstate}
 {\pretocmd{\lstlisting}{\NoAutoSpacing}{}{}}
 {\pretocmd{\lstlisting}{\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=0 }{}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
a:b:c
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This should be compatible with the new release of Babel 3.9 that uses `\XeTeXinterchartokenstate` when XeLaTeX is used (Polyglossia already does it). I tested it on the prerelease version of TeX Live 2013.

Comment: It is working on TL2012 as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working with TL2013 too, had the same issue with minted.

Answer (score 1):

Babel with French option makes : an active character.
You can locally disable this behaviour with `\shorthandoff{:}` and re-enable it with `\shorthandon{:}`.

This would give the following (untested) code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec,listings} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, columns=fixed}

\begin{document}

\shorthandoff{:}
\begin{lstlisting}
a:b:c
\end{lstlisting}
\shorthandon{:}

\end{document}
```

I based this answer on [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74860/unexpected-clash-between-babel-and-pgf-spy).

Comment: This isn't working. As far as I know, the `listings` environment should disable the shorthands itself, which it does with `pdflatex`.

Comment: This isn't working right off the bat, but when compiling this, xelatex invited me to use \NoAutoSpacing "inside a group". Apparently it's a feature from frenchb.dtx. I'll try to figure out how to include it automatically in listings.

Comment: ``\shorthandon``  doesn't work with ``XeLaTeX``, which is a shame because it is often convenient to compile with ``XeLaTeX`` when typing in foreign languages like French.