# Coloring numbers outside string and variables using lstlisting and parsing don't work as expected. Need Help to fix with PDFLaTeX

Tags: color, listings, parsing, number, lstdefinestyle

I am writing my thesis and i need to put extract of code into it. Having developed all my C# code in Visual Studio, I would like to have more or less the same colors, so I have taken different different approach found among all the question here on this website.

### **This is what i obtained:**

[image: Example of code]
[image: some example of coloring numbers, the 0,2 colored uses escape characters]

### **this is what I expected:**

[image]
[image]

### **The problem**

is the same as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569914/listings-consistently-colouring-numbers) but the problem there wasn't resolved with PDFLaTeX and I didn't managed to use one of the solution with my project.

> Edit: in a nutshell, I would like numbers to be highlighted if:
>
> they come after any of the following characters:  , ., (, {,[, :
> they come before any of the following characters:  , ., ), }, ], :, ;
> but definitely not include _ in either group as that might break the variable naming >convention in many snippets of code (even though Python does accept _ in numbers to aid the visual identification of groups of 10^3, as in x = 1_000_000.

in particular I would like to manage to color "f" of float to color like numbers and to be able to color automatically color numbers followed by a comma.

### **This is my working code:**

Regarding to the the code of the above cited question, my code is edited in the parse section to achieve more specific of mine and had a patchcmd to include ) into the parsing also using breaklines=true.

[please read comments into the style definition to understand some problem and choice of mine. Could be right as wrong.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter

%%% Copied from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500690/23765
% Some conditional tests
\def\@genericif#1{#1\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}
\def\@ifdigit#1{\@genericif{\ifnum1<1\noexpand#1\relax}}
\def\@ifempty#1{\@genericif{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax}}

% The main parsing macros
\def\parse@num#1{%
    \@ifempty{#1}%
    {\parse@num@false}%
    {\@genericif{\parsesign}%
        {\parse@num@sign#1{}\@end}%
        {\parse@num@dig#1{}\@end}%
    }%
}
% Parse sign
\def\parse@num@sign#1#2\@end{%
    \@genericif{\ifx\parse@num@minus#1}%
    {\@ifempty{#2}{\parse@num@false}{\parse@num@dig#2\@end}}%
    {\@genericif{\ifx\parse@num@plus#1}%
        {\@ifempty{#2}{\parse@num@false}{\parse@num@dig#2\@end}}%
        {\@genericif{\ifx\parse@num@div#1}%
            {\@ifempty{#2}{\parse@num@false}{\parse@num@dig#2\@end}}%
            {\@genericif{\ifx\parse@num@mul#1}%
                {\@ifempty{#2}{\parse@num@false}{\parse@num@dig#2\@end}}%
                {\parse@num@dig#1#2\@end}%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}
% Parse first digit
\def\parse@num@dig#1#2\@end{%
    \@ifdigit{#1}%
    {\@ifempty{#2}{\parse@num@true}{\parse@num@digs#2\@end}}%
    {\parse@num@false}%
}
% Parse optional following digits
\def\parse@num@digs#1#2\@end{%
    \@ifdigit{#1}{%
        \@ifempty{#2}%
        {\parse@num@true}%
        {\parse@num@digs#2\@end}%
    }{%
        \@genericif{\parsefloat}{%
            \@genericif{\ifx\parse@num@point#1}%
            {\@ifempty{#2}{\parse@num@false}{\parse@num@decs#2\@end}}%
            {\@genericif{\ifx\parse@num@comma#1}%
                {\@ifempty{#2}{\parse@num@true}{\parse@num@decs#2\@end}}%
                {\parse@num@fleffe#1\@end}%
            }%
        }%
        {\parse@num@false}%
    }%
}

% Parse decimal places
\def\parse@num@decs#1#2\@end{%
    \@ifdigit{#1}{%
        \@ifempty{#2}%
        {\parse@num@true}%
        {\@genericif{\ifx\parse@num@comma#2}%
            {\parse@num@false}% 
            {\parse@num@endings#2\@end}%
        }%
    }%
    {\@genericif{\ifx\parse@num@comma#1}%
        {\@ifempty{#2}{\parse@num@true}{\parse@num@false}}%
        {\parse@num@fleffe#1\@end}%
    }%
}


% parse f
\def\parse@num@fleffe#1#2\@end{%
    \@genericif{\ifx\parse@num@effe#1}{%
        \@ifempty{#2}%
        {\parse@num@true}%
        {\parse@num@digs#2\@end}%
    }{\parse@num@false}%
}

%parse after first digit of decs
\def\parse@num@endings#1#2\@end{%
    \@ifdigit{#1}{%
        \@ifempty{#2}%
        {\parse@num@true}%
        {\parse@num@fleffe#2\@end}%
    }%
    {\parse@num@fleffe#1\@end}%
}

% User interface
\newcommand\ifnumber[4][]{%
    \begingroup
    \let\parsesign=\iftrue
    \let\parsefloat=\iftrue
    \let\parse@num@minus=-%
    \let\parse@num@plus=+%
    \let\parse@num@point=.%
    \let\parse@num@effe=f%
    \let\parse@num@div=/%
    \let\parse@num@mul=*%
    \let\parse@num@comma=,%
    #1%
    \def\parse@num@true{\endgroup#3}%
    \def\parse@num@false{\endgroup#4}%
    \parse@num{#2}%
}   


%%% Additions to the listings package
\lst@Key{numbersstyle}{}{\def\lst@numbersstyle{#1}}
\lst@Key{parsenumbers}{false}[t]{\lstKV@SetIf{#1}\lst@ifparsenumbers}

\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}{%
    \lst@ifparsenumbers
    % Only if mode changes are not prohibited
    \lst@ifmode\else
    \expandafter\@hook@ifnumber\the\lst@token\@end
    {\let\lst@thestyle=\lst@numbersstyle}%
    {}%
    \fi
    \fi
}
\def\@hook@ifnumber#1#2\@end{%
    \@genericif{\ifx\lst@nolig#1}%
    {\@hook@ifnumber@{#2}}%
    {\@hook@ifnumber@{#1#2}}%
}

\def\@hook@ifnumber@{%
    \ifnumber[\expandafter\let\expandafter\parse@num@minus\csname lst@um-\endcsname]%
}

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{lillagithub}{RGB}{177,104,222}
\definecolor{typeColor}{RGB}{134, 198, 145}%{134, 193, 120}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%colori VS mio
%white -> default white for black backgorunds %normal text, operators, expression, parenthesis
\definecolor{blueVS}{RGB}{53, 131, 213} %access modifier, method parameters, acess, literal, contextual, query
\definecolor{violetVS}{RGB}{200,160,219}%{176,156,223} %statement, iterator
\definecolor{tealVS}{RGB}{58, 176, 166} %namespace, class name
\definecolor{cyanVS}{RGB}{104,198,252} %variables
\definecolor{paleyellowVS}{RGB}{220,220,170} %methods
\definecolor{orangeVS}{RGB}{214,157,133} %strings
\definecolor{blackBackgroundVS}{RGB}{30,30,30} %background dark theme
\definecolor{greenfinchVS}{RGB}{77,166,66} %comments
\definecolor{lightGreenVS}{RGB}{179, 206, 153} %numbers
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\lsthk@SelectCharTable}{)}{`}{}{} % to color number with closed roun parenthesis 
\makeatother 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\lstdefinestyle{CSstyle} {
    language=[Sharp]C,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{white}, 
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{blueVS}, 
    numbersep=5pt,
    tabsize=2,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true, %%%%%%%%%%%
    frame=b, 
    linewidth=150mm,
    stringstyle=\color{orangeVS}\ttfamily,
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    xleftmargin=17pt,
    framexleftmargin=17pt,
    framexrightmargin=5pt,
    framexbottommargin=0pt,
    commentstyle=\color{greenfinchVS},
    morecomment=[l]{//}, %use comment-line-style!
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, %for multiline comments
    showstringspaces=false,
    backgroundcolor=\color{blackBackgroundVS},
    identifierstyle=\color{cyanVS}, 
    keywordstyle=\color{blueVS},
    escapeinside={@@},
    parsenumbers = true,
    numbersstyle=\color{lightGreenVS}, 
    classoffset=0,
    morekeywords={abstract, async, const, event, extern, in, new, out, override, readonly, sealed, static, unsafe, virtual, volatile, public, protected, internal, private, params, in, ref, out, class, interface, struct, enum, delegate, namespace, extern, alias, null, true, false, default, add, and, async, await, dynamic, get, global, init, nint, not, nuint, or, partial, record, remove, set, value, var, when, where, checked, unchecked, fixed, lock, continue, bool, byte, sbyte, char, decimal, double, float, int, uint, nint, nuint, long, ulong, short, ushort, bool, byte, sbyte, char, decimal, double, float, int, uint, nint, nuint, long, ulong, short, ushort},
    classoffset=1,
    morekeywords={Vector2,Vector3,Bounds},
    keywordstyle=\color{typeColor},
    classoffset=2,
    emph={using, while, yield, return, break, throw, try, catch, finally, if, switch, do, for, foreach, while, goto},
    emphstyle=\color{violetVS},
    classoffset = 3,
    otherkeywords={;,=,!,!=,~,\&,+,-,\^,\%,<-,<<-,>,>=,<,<=,(,),[,],\{,\},\\,|}, %cannot add / * because are used for comment
    morekeywords={;,=,!,!=,~,\&,+,-,\^,\%,<-,<<-,\_,/,>,>=,<,<=,(,),[,],\{,\},\\,|}, %if i add comma to other and more keywords, it will always be of the same color of keyword[0] (blueVS), but if i add it here, the number is recognized from the parsing algorithm
    keywordstyle=\color{white},
    classoffset=4,
    morekeywords={CalculateBoundWorlds,TransformPoint, GetComponent,OnMouseDrag,OnMouseDown,OnMouseUp,DragCamera,setLastPosView,ScreenToViewportPoint,Limit2Bound,Translate},
    keywordstyle=\color{paleyellowVS},
    classoffset=6,
    morekeywords={Camera,BackgroundBoundsCalculator, MonoBehaviour, Tooltip, HideInInspector, SerializeField, SpriteRenderer,Sprite},
    keywordstyle=\color{tealVS}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{blue}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\hspace{15pt}#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white, singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={bf,footnotesize}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    \begin{lstlisting}[language={[Sharp]C}, caption={C\# exaple}, label={Script}, style=CSstyle]
        using System.Collections;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using UnityEngine;
        public class BackgroundBoundsCalculator : MonoBehavior
        {
            /*aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa*/
            public Vector2[] CalculateBoundWorlds()
            {
                string s = "stringa"
                SpriteRenderer m_SpriteRenderer = @gameObject@.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
                Sprite sprite = m_SpriteRenderer.@sprite@;
                
                Bounds bounds = sprite.@bounds@;
                Vector3 max, min;
                max = bounds.@max@;
                min = bounds.@min@;
                
                Vector3 xBound = @transform@.TransformPoint(min.@x@, max.@x@, 0);
                Vector3 yBound = @transform@.TransformPoint(min.@y@, max.@y@, 0);
                
                //v1
                Vector2[] boundWorlds = new Vector2[2];
                boundWorlds[0] = new Vector2(xBound.@x@, xBound.@y@);
                boundWorlds[1] = new Vector2(yBound.@x@, yBound.@y@);
                if(){}
                return boundWorlds;
                
            }
        }
    
        
        var d = 5f;
        Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(1, 2f, 3);     
        (1) [2] {3} <4> |5| \6\ /7/ !8! (9} {10]    
        
        0.1 0,2 0, 2, 2. .2 ,7 *3*
        0@,@2
        2@,@
        +1 -2 *3 /4
        float prova = 4.5;
        3.4f 5f
        .3. 6*
        0@f@
        //5
        ///
        4.20f,
        27,
        27f.
    \end{lstlisting}
    
    \pagebreak
    \newcommand\testnum[2][]{%
        \makebox[5em][l]{#2}%
        \makebox[5em][l]{\ifnumber[#1]{#2}{yes}{no}}%
    }
    \ttfamily
    default setting\par
    \testnum{}
    \testnum{0}\par
    \testnum{1}
    \testnum{12345}\par
    \testnum{+}
    \testnum{+123}\par
    \testnum{-}
    \testnum{-123}\par
    \testnum{-0}
    \testnum{+0}\par
    \testnum{0.}
    \testnum{0.123}\par
    \testnum{-.1}
    \testnum{-+123}\par
    \testnum{-0.123}
    \testnum{+0.123}\par
    \testnum{abc}
    \testnum{123abc}\par
    
    
    \medskip
    \makeatletter
    \string\modificaMia\par
    \testnum[]{-123,45}
    \testnum[]{0,}\par
    \testnum[]{,2}
    \testnum[]{4.20f,}\par
    \testnum[]{3.}
    \testnum[]{7.2f}\par
    \testnum[]{/6}
    \testnum[]{*3}\par
    \testnum[]{+1}
    \testnum[]{7f}\par
    \testnum[]{6,3}
    \testnum[]{7,3,}\par
    \testnum[]{+1.8f}
    \testnum[]{27,5f}\par
    \testnum[]{123,4f}
    \testnum[]{?}\par
    \makeatother
\end{document}
```

### **The Output:**

- The Two excpeted screenshot of above
- testing part where i assure that the parse is working showe below

[image]

as you can see in the last screenshot, there are different ways to parse for a number. In  particular, i would like to see all the numbers that "say yes" to be colored "f" inclusive. Not the comma when is the last character (meaning is a normal comma like a parameter in a new Vector(1, 2, 3);

In a nutshell, I would like to obtain the same result of the second expected screenshot.

Please help me, I think once is finished, this code would be useful also for everyone that wants the same color palette of VisualStudio for his project, in fact i was thinking about to post it on my githbub once finished, but I dind't manage to finish it yet...

Comment: well nobody found a good pdflatex solution in the question you linked too, so I doubt that you will get one now. So why don't you use lualatex or minted?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Nobody posted a good pdflatex, i don't think it means nobody found a solution of that kind. Anyway I wold like to find a solution that is good for everything not depending on compilation. I have never used minted and for what i could understand is not customizable  as lstlisting